# How to receive a message from the server in a client? (UDP)

Tags: c++, udp, client-server

I'm trying to receive a message from the server in my client, and although I don't get any compiling errors, my buffer won't take what the server is sending. I've tried changing the parameters in `recvfrom` in the client to correlate to the parameters used in the client's `sendto` but the same thing happens, my memset buffer remains empty. I've also tried just sending a simple null terminated char array of size two to test it, and the same result occurs.

Server:

```
    int sockfd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    int rv;
    int numbytes;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
    char buf[MAXBUFLEN];
    socklen_t addr_len;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // set to AF_INET to force IPv4
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, MYPORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                p->ai_protocol)) == -1) 
            perror("listener: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("listener: bind");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "listener: failed to bind socket\n");
        return 2;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

    while(1){

    addr_len = sizeof their_addr;
    if ((numbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, MAXBUFLEN-1 , 0,
        (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_len)) == -1) {
        perror("recvfrom");
        exit(1);
    }

    buf[numbytes] = '\0';

    string toRespond = theMove(buf, AG);  
    char * sendBack = new char[toRespond.size() + 1];
    std::copy(toRespond.begin(), toRespond.end(), sendBack);
    sendBack[toRespond.size()] = '\0';

    sendto(sockfd, testing, strlen(testing), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, addr_len);

}
```

Client:

```
    int sockfd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    struct sockaddr_storage src_addr;
    socklen_t src_addr_len = sizeof(src_addr);
    int rv;
    int numbytes;

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage: talker hostname message\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(argv[1], SERVERPORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and make a socket
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("talker: socket");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "talker: failed to bind socket\n");
        return 2;
    }

    char * chatBuff = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*512);

   while(1){

   scanf("%s", chatBuff);
   if ((numbytes = sendto(sockfd, chatBuff, strlen(chatBuff), 0,
             p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen)) == -1) {
        perror("talker: sendto");
        exit(1);
    }
    memset(chatBuff, '\0', sizeof(chatBuff));

   if (recvfrom(sockfd, chatBuff, strlen(chatBuff), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&src_addr, &src_addr_len) == -1)

    {
        puts("throw computer out the stacks");
    }

    puts(chatBuff);

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

    printf("talker: sent %d bytes to %s\n", numbytes, argv[1]);
    memset(chatBuff, '\0', sizeof(chatBuff));

   }
```

Comment: why do u free servinfo in client's while?

Comment: First port of call, man strlen.

Comment: Debugging 101 - if you have a call that fails, load all the value parameters into temp local vars first and print them out.  Either that, or use an actual debugger to check them.  Do that BEFORE posting here.

Answer (score 1):

```
memset(chatBuff, '\0', sizeof(chatBuff));
```

While not actually incorrect, this initializing of the entire buffer is cargo-cult nonsense when you intend to load it in the next line with a call that retuns the number of bytes loaded - that return would allow you to ensure a null-terminated string by setting one byte only.  The only thing you must remember is that you must leave enough space for the null, either by oversizing the buffer or reducing the read length requested.

```
if (recvfrom(sockfd, chatBuff, strlen(chatBuff), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&src_addr, &src_addr_len) == -1)
```

In the (unnecessary and wasteful) line above, you use 'sizeof(chatBuff)' as the buffer size but then here, inexplicably, you shove in 'strlen(chatBuff)' - a RUNTIME CALL that returns the size of a null-terminated char array.  Since you just set that array to all null, it returns zero, so your recvfrom() will always return with a 'buffer too small' error unless you receive an empty datagram.

So:

```
int bytesRec=recvfrom(sockfd, chatBuff, sizeof(chatBuff)-1, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&src_addr, &src_addr_len);
if(bytesRec<1) puts("throw computer out the stacks")
else chatBuff[bytesRec]=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your server code, you are passing some unknown buffer named `testing` as the buffer to send, but you should be passing the `sendBack` buffer instead:

```
sendto(sockfd, sendBack, strlen(sendBack), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, addr_len);
```

For that matter, you can eliminate `sendBack` and send the data from `toRespond` directly instead:

```
sendto(sockfd, toRespond.c_str(), toResponse.size(), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, addr_len);
```

In both your server and client code, you are using `AF_UNSPEC` when calling `getaddrinfo()`.  That is OK in a server, but generally not OK in a client.  Imagine what happens if the server binds to an IPv6 address, but the client creates an IPv4 socket, or vice versa.  Obvious mismatch, communication will not be possible (unless the server creates a dual-stack IPv6 socket that can accept both IPv4 and IPv6 packets).  So in your client code, you should not use `AF_UNSPEC`.  Use either `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6`, depending on what the server is actually bound to.  If you must use `AF_UNSPEC` on the client side, then you need to call `sendto()` and `recvfrom()` for every possible server IP address until you receive a response from one of them.

Lastly, in your client code, your call to `recvfrom()` is assuming the response data will be no more than the same size as the data sent with `sendto()`. Is that actually the case?  You did not show what `theMove()` does to the data the server receives, or how it generates a response.  At the very least, you should replace `strlen()` with 512 when calling `recvfrom()`.  Your client code is also assuming that the server's response will be null-terminated, but the server is not sending a null terminator in the data it echoes.  So you need to terminate the buffer that you are passing to `puts()`.